# Show that time derivative of creation-annihilation operators of Klein-Gordon field are zero

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

For example, for the annihilation operator

\begin{equation}
a(\vec{k}) = C \int d^3x e^{i k\cdot x}\partial^ \leftrightarrow _t\phi(x),
\end{equation}

where C is a constant that I will ignore, the time derivative gives

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_t a(\vec{k}) &= \int d^3x[e^{i\cdot x}(\nabla^2-m^2)\phi(x) - (\partial_t^2e^{ik\cdot x})\phi(x)]\\
&= \int d^3 x[(-\partial_t^2 + \nabla^2-m^2)e^{ik\cdot x}]\times \phi(x).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This second step, the movement of the Laplacian, is what I don't get. Perhaps is more difficult in what I use but, is it not just to use the Laplacian identity

\begin{equation}
\nabla^2(fg) = f\nabla^2g + 2\nabla f\cdot \nabla g + g\nabla^2f?
\end{equation}

If this is true, then why the integral $\int d^3x\nabla e^{ik\cdot x}\cdot\nabla\phi(x)$ and $\int d^3x \nabla^2(e^{ik\cdot x}\phi(x))$ must be zero?

Comment: Is this from a textbook? Which page? Presumably the textbook assumes that $\phi(x)$ and derivatives vanish at spatial boundaries.

Comment: Yes, it's [Ashok](https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Quantum-Field-Theory-Ashok/dp/9812832866/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=quantum+field+theory+ashok&qid=1563483108&s=gateway&sr=8-1) p177 Eq. (5.62). It has the assumption that $\phi$ is local, Eq. (5.3); but as always, I'm not sure if e.g. $\int dx \nabla \phi=0$.

Comment: Indeed Ashok states below eq. (5.62) that he has _integrated the space derivatives by parts assuming that the surface terms vanish (see (5.3))._

Comment: So... again... it doesn't really matter if I have $\phi$ or $\nabla \phi$ inside the volume integral, right?

Answer (score 2):

The difference 
$$
(\nabla^2 f)g- f(\nabla^2 g)= \nabla\cdot((\nabla  f)g - g(\nabla g)
$$ is a total divergence, so its integral over all ${\mathbb R}^3$ is treated as being zero.

This is strictly true only for periodic boundary conditions or for $\phi(x)$ vanishing at infinity. Of course the operator quantum field $\phi(x)$ does not itself vanish at infinity, neither does the plane-wave $e^{ikx}$, but in all these infinite volume field-theory expressions we have in the back of minds that we are really  construcing  *wave-packet* annihilators. In other words   $a(k)\to a(f)$ in which we replace  $e^{ikx}\to f(x)$ with $f(x)$ being a smooth function that is  unity in the region of interest but  vanishes as $x\to  \infty$. Locally you will not be able to tell the difference between $a(k)\equiv a(e^{ikx})$ and $a(f)$.

Comment: Uhmm, "the operator quantum field $\phi(x)$ does not itself vanish at infinity", is this not "wrong"? I mean, at least in a general QFT course, one always assumes local field, right?

Comment: The field operator mode expansion $\phi(x)=\int(a e^{ikx}+a^\dagger e^{-ikx})dk $ clearly does not vanish at infinity -- but "yes" we tacitly assume that it does. My point is that we are always secretly assuming that we take matrix elements between localized  wave-packet states. This is the same as the "in"  "out" field limits in LSZ.  The problem is purely pedagogical in that that explicitly including the wave-packets makes the math look too complicated for intro classes.

Comment: Ah... so the it's really after we take the matrix elements. Much appreciatted.